# Use an Address Field with 3 lines for the street

Tags: 8, entities, forms

I'm working on an Entity where I created a field containing Address informations (like country, city and street).

The default Address Type in Drupal 8 supports only 2 lines for the street information. Is there a way to add an extra line?

Comment: There is an issue on Drupal.org to address this:
https://www.drupal.org/project/address/issues/2482969 Once it's resolved that would be the ideal way to support 3 lines in address.

Answer (score 1):

I found a (partial solution), but new ideas are always well welcomed.
I used the field organization as third row and then I rearranged the weights of the fields in this way:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'specific_add_form' || $form_id == 'specific_edit_form' ) {
        $form['field_address']['widget'][0]['address']['#after_build'][] = 'mymodule_weight_change';
    }

}

function mymodule_weight_change($element, $form_state) {
    $element['country_code']['#weight'] = -10;
    $element['address_line1']['#weight'] = -7;
    $element['address_line2']['#weight'] = -5;
    $element['organization']['#weight'] = -2;
    $element['postal_code']['#weight'] = 5;
    $element['locality']['#weight'] = 10;

    return $element;
}
```

Endly I put the css of the organization label as `display: none`.

Comment: another way could be puts a new text field inside your entity and then using javascript to move the field inside tyhe form.